# Node.js let's encrypt file upload error in Chrome

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, ssl, sails.js, lets-encrypt

With SSL enabled in my Node.js (Sails.js) app, I am not able to upload large files. My upload was working fine without SSL. At the moment, with SSL configured, I can only upload very small files. I am using "let's encrypt" for SSL certificates. I also realized that this behavior is only visible in google chrome (Version 47.0.2526.106 m), where if I upload over 100Kb files it returns me a `302 Moved Temporarily`. Firefox seems to be doing fine.

Comment: This has nothing to do with let´s encrypt certificate but rather with chrome or chrome+node app combination.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [client side websocket restricting message length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886320/client-side-websocket-restricting-message-length)